# VB.NET 2019 - Create Project with Entity Framework in a Class Library Project

Tags: vb.net

My solution consist of: 
Windows Forms Project
Windows Service Project

Currently my EF6 (which connects to SQL Server) exists within the Windows Forms Project. However I would rather want to create a Class Library Project (.Net Core) where my EF6 can reside. That way I can easily reference the EF6 DbContext in the Windows Service Project and well as later in a Mobile App.

Problem is, even after adding the NuGet packages to a Class Library Project, it doesn't give the option to add a ADO.NET Entity DataModel to the Class Library Project.

Is there some kind of limitation to VB.NET for this? Or am I using the wrong project type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I used the wrong type of Class Library

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use  Class Library (.Net FrameWork) which creates a DLL .So that you can later share it with other project types including Mobile (Xamarain) or Web Api

Also Try to do it in same solution for easy reference and build (not mandatory)
[image]